# How a large database website is made to handle many different services?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting

In many websites, they can offer a variety of services.

For example, on https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov, there are

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/

...

The services are quite different, which should be maintained by different groups of people in an organization. The services should be hosted on different physical servers to serve a larger number of web requests although it appears to be just a single domain.

But I don't quite understand how this is done. How to make multiples physical servers appear to be a single domain? Could anybody let me know what is the current software technology to do this?

Comment: Proxies and load balancers ...

Answer (score 1):

These are reverse-proxied. You can set up master web-server so that contents of other servers appear as sub-directories of reverse-proxy.

For example, how to set up: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

This could be used for variety of purposes.

For example, every real server host has a prviate IP, and to expose them all into internet we required to use some NAT or proxying. If there are many servers, there is no option other than proxying, because you can't set up nat to multiple hosts.

Another reason would be to have all of them shared cookies; web-client will send same cookies to each sub-directory because from its point of view this is a single web host. Same thing with another same-origin policies.

The third reason is HTTPS striping: the master host has HTTPS certificates, it is securely managed for that by some team. Then reverse proxying is done via HTTP (without encryption) over physically protected wire.

A last example is load sharing, where you set up proxying to a bunch of servers and forward request to that is least loaded.